# Input elements inside table cells - not following overflow:hidden property

Tags: css, html

I have a table, a few  elements have input elements inside them. I have set the following properties for the input elements.

```
table input{
    width:inherit;
    margin:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Now i want the cell size to determine the input element size, hence the inherit property. But because i have a margin set on them, they were popping out of the cells a little. So i added the overflow:hidden property, but thats not helping.

What am i doing wrong?

Edit:Code Added

```
    <div>
    <form>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th class="tinycolumn">S.no</th>
        <th>Part Name</th>
        <th>Part number</th>
        <th class="tinycolumn">Qty</th>
        <th>New/Repair</th>
        <th>MRP</th>
        <th>Denting/Fitting</th>
        <th>Painting</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="0"></td>
        <td><select><option value="new">New</option><option value="repair">Repair</option></select></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="tel"></td>
        <td><input type="tel"></td>    
        <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><button>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit">
</form>

     </div>
```

Supporting CSS

```
#estimatetable{
display:inline-block;
width:80%;
margin:1em auto 1em auto;
overflow:hidden;
}
#estimatetable form{
width:auto;
}
#estimatetable form table{
text-align:center;
width:100%;
}
#estimatetable tr{
min-height:3em;
}
#estimatetable form table tr td, #estimatetable form table tr th{
border:1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
max-width:2em;
padding:1px;
}
#estimatetable input, #estimatetable select{
width:inherit;
margin:1px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#estimatetable button{
width:100%;
}
#estimatetable .tinycolumn{
max-width:.5em;
}
```

Comment: try adding `table-layout: fixed;` to the table

Comment: you should use the box-sizing propertie to include border within width calculation for input

Comment: @Pete That didn't work, only it made all the cells of a standard size

Comment: @GCyrillus Could you explain with a little code.

Comment: ah wasn't sure if it would, table cells usually expand to take the width of the elements inside if they are wider.  As GCyrillus says try using adding `box-sizing: border-box; width:100%;` to your input styles

Comment: @GCyrillus Code Added

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS says : input inherits `width` of parent.

In regular box model, borders are added to `width`.

Using `box-sizing:border-box;` , `border` and `padding` will be included in total width of element.

Your CSS can be fixed this way :

```
table input{
    width:inherit;
    box-sizing:border-box; /* add vendor prefix or a script to do so if needed */
    }
```

If you still wish to use the `margin:1px;` you should turn it into `padding:1px;` to parent element (`td`) and apply to it as well the `box-sizing` propertie.

---

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/FivKH)**

Comment: I do understand how the use of padding will change border placing. But i am just not getting why the overflow property is not working. Shouldn't it just get deleted off. I also now realise that if it did work the way i want it to, it would probably remove my borders on the right side. So what would be the best way to do this. I need my input elements, to resize based on the size of the cell and stay within the borders. All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: overflow does not apply to table because tables expand/shrinks to its content. padding on td instead of margin on input have nothing to do with border spacing. you are mixing up all of these